# Fortify- spring-boot-starter-actuator deserialization vulnerability with latest spring boot version

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, fortify

I am facing Dynamic Code Evaluation: Unsafe Deserialization in fortify scan with latest spring boot version 2.2.4 Release. can you anyone help to resolve this issue?